# How to send jwt token in json format?

Tags: python, jwt, flask-restful

I'm trying to figure out API with python. And want to send back some already encrypted jwt token.

When I'm trying to return jwt token in **return** method sends back Error's and Error's page in postman app shows up. But when printing it inside console everything works fine.

```
class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        un = json_data['username']
        pw = json_data['password']
        encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({'username': un, 'password': pw}, 'OH HI MARK', algorithm='HS256')
        print(encoded_jwt)
        return jsonify(token = encoded_jwt)
```

I'm excpecting to get this token  `

> b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImhpIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9.MQ-hwWabt13E4KMFxPztSUr6RYwsZZ-tT0sdv2s0vU0'

But getting bunch of error.

Edit:
Asked to add Error's.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\Yeah\app.py", line 16, in post
    return jsonify(token = encoded_jwt)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 321, in jsonify
    dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators) + '\n',
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "D:\FinallySomethingWork\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 81, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says:

> TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

That means, `encoded_jwt` is a byte array which can't be serialized into a JSON.
You first have to convert it to a string:

```
return jsonify(token = encoded_jwt.decode("utf-8"))
```

On a sidenote: don't put the password into the token!